# Rake db:migrate has conflicting test-unit gem dependencies (1.2.3 required, 2.3.0 installed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm trying to run

```
rake db:migrate
```

However each time I do I get the following errors:

```
rake aborted!
can't activate test-unit (= 1.2.3), already activated test-unit-2.3.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
/Users/petenixey/project/Rakefile:12:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Peters-MacBook-Air:pingpanel petenixey$
```

I have other gems that have dependencies on test-unti 2.3.0 and I can't seem to find anyone else with the same issue.

I've been having a bit of a rubbish time with gem issues recently, would be very grateful for any advice people have. Thank you

**Edit** 
The other thing I've noticed is that if I create a completely fresh Rails project using the gemfiles and gemsets below, rake db:migrate *does* work. This would suggest to me that something is wrong in an environment setting or similar but I can't figure out what.

---------------- full errors from running with --trace

```
rake aborted!
can't activate test-unit (= 1.2.3), already activated test-unit-2.3.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:150:in `block in replace_gem'
/Users/petenixey/project/tasks/rspec.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `block in load'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in `block in load_tasks'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in `each'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:131:in `load_tasks'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:141:in `load_tasks'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/petenixey/Dropbox/rails/pingpanel/Rakefile:12:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `block in run'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/petenixey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@test/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

-------------- Gemfile

```
source :rubygems

gem "authlogic"
gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 0.2.6'
gem "hoptoad_notifier"
gem "rake"
gem "rails", ">=3.0.7"
gem "heroku"

group :development, :test do
  # up to date
  gem "faker"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem "ruby-debug19"
  gem "capybara", ">= 0.4.1.2"
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem "rspec-rails" 
  gem 'test-unit'
end

gem "launchy"
gem "autotest"
gem "autotest-growl"
gem "autotest-rails-pure"
gem "autotest-fsevent"
gem 'metric_fu'
```

----------------- Gemfile lock

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    Saikuro (1.1.0)
    ZenTest (4.5.0)
    abstract (1.0.0)
    actionmailer (3.0.7)
      actionpack (= 3.0.7)
      mail (~> 2.2.15)
    actionpack (3.0.7)
      activemodel (= 3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      erubis (~> 2.6.6)
      i18n (~> 0.5.0)
      rack (~> 1.2.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.6.14)
      rack-test (~> 0.5.7)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activemodel (3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5.0)
    activerecord (3.0.7)
      activemodel (= 3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
      arel (~> 2.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activeresource (3.0.7)
      activemodel (= 3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
    activesupport (3.0.7)
    archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
    arel (2.0.10)
    arrayfields (4.7.4)
    authlogic (3.0.3)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.7)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.7)
    autotest (4.4.6)
      ZenTest (>= 4.4.1)
    autotest-fsevent (0.2.5)
      sys-uname
    autotest-growl (0.2.9)
    autotest-rails-pure (4.1.2)
    builder (2.1.2)
    capybara (0.4.1.2)
      celerity (>= 0.7.9)
      culerity (>= 0.2.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 0.0.27)
      xpath (~> 0.1.3)
    celerity (0.8.9)
    childprocess (0.1.9)
      ffi (~> 1.0.6)
    chronic (0.3.0)
    churn (0.0.13)
      chronic (>= 0.2.3)
      hirb
      json_pure
      main
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0.4)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0.3)
    colored (1.2)
    columnize (0.3.2)
    configuration (1.2.0)
    cucumber (0.10.2)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.2)
      gherkin (>= 2.3.5)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
      term-ansicolor (>= 1.0.5)
    cucumber-rails (0.4.1)
      cucumber (>= 0.10.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.7)
    culerity (0.2.15)
    database_cleaner (0.6.7)
    diff-lcs (1.1.2)
    erubis (2.6.6)
      abstract (>= 1.0.0)
    factory_girl (1.3.3)
    factory_girl_rails (1.0.1)
      factory_girl (~> 1.3)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (0.9.5)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
    fattr (2.2.0)
    ffi (1.0.8)
    flay (1.4.2)
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0)
    flog (2.5.1)
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0)
    gherkin (2.3.8)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
    haml (3.1.1)
    heroku (2.1.4)
      launchy (>= 0.3.2)
      rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
      term-ansicolor (~> 1.0.5)
    hirb (0.4.5)
    hoptoad_notifier (2.4.9)
      activesupport
      builder
    i18n (0.5.0)
    jquery-rails (1.0.5)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.5.1)
    json_pure (1.5.1)
    launchy (0.4.0)
      configuration (>= 0.0.5)
      rake (>= 0.8.1)
    linecache19 (0.5.12)
      ruby_core_source (>= 0.1.4)
    mail (2.2.19)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.6)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    main (4.4.0)
      arrayfields (>= 4.7.4)
      fattr (>= 2.1.0)
    metric_fu (2.1.1)
      Saikuro (>= 1.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.0.0)
      chronic (~> 0.3.0)
      churn (>= 0.0.7)
      flay (>= 1.2.1)
      flog (>= 2.3.0)
      rails_best_practices (>= 0.6.4)
      rcov (>= 0.8.3.3)
      reek (>= 1.2.6)
      roodi (>= 2.1.0)
      syntax
    mime-types (1.16)
    nokogiri (1.4.4)
    polyglot (0.3.1)
    rack (1.2.2)
    rack-mount (0.6.14)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-test (0.5.7)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.0.7)
      actionmailer (= 3.0.7)
      actionpack (= 3.0.7)
      activerecord (= 3.0.7)
      activeresource (= 3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.0.7)
    rails_best_practices (0.9.0)
      activesupport
      colored
      erubis
      haml
      i18n
      ruby-progressbar
      ruby_parser
    railties (3.0.7)
      actionpack (= 3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (~> 0.14.4)
    rake (0.8.7)
    rcov (0.9.9)
    reek (1.2.8)
      ruby2ruby (~> 1.2)
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0)
    rest-client (1.6.1)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    roodi (2.1.0)
      ruby_parser
    rspec (2.6.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.6.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.6.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.6.0)
    rspec-core (2.6.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
    rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
    rspec-rails (2.6.0)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.6.0)
    ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      linecache19 (>= 0.5.11)
      ruby_core_source (>= 0.1.4)
    ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      linecache19 (>= 0.5.11)
      ruby-debug-base19 (>= 0.11.19)
    ruby-progressbar (0.0.10)
    ruby2ruby (1.2.5)
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0)
    ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
      archive-tar-minitar (>= 0.5.2)
    ruby_parser (2.0.6)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.4)
    selenium-webdriver (0.2.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.1.7)
      ffi (>= 1.0.7)
      json_pure
      rubyzip
    sexp_processor (3.0.5)
    sqlite3 (1.3.3)
    sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
      sqlite3 (>= 1.3.3)
    syntax (1.0.0)
    sys-uname (0.8.5)
    term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
    test-unit (2.3.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    treetop (1.4.9)
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.27)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  authlogic
  autotest
  autotest-fsevent
  autotest-growl
  autotest-rails-pure
  capybara (>= 0.4.1.2)
  cucumber-rails
  database_cleaner
  factory_girl_rails
  faker
  heroku
  hoptoad_notifier
  jquery-rails (>= 0.2.6)
  launchy
  metric_fu
  rails (>= 3.0.7)
  rspec-rails
  ruby-debug19
  sqlite3-ruby
  test-unit
```

Comment: Can you also let us know your list of installed gems (`gem list`) and/or your Gemfile (if you're using rails 3)

Comment: Added - thanks Chris. I am using Rails 3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally fixed this. Thank god for being able to create rails projects from scratch and add things in one by one.

By gradually adding in each set of settings and initialisers between my new fresh project and old project I finally narrowed the problem down to the rspec.rake file in:

```
/lib/tasks/rspec.rake
```

I'm using rspec-rails (i.e. Rspec 2 running on Rails 3). The problem was that this rspec.rake file is not actually required in rspec-rails and apparently also screws things up.

Just to verify this I ran a fresh install of rspec-rails (rails generate rspec:install) and noted that the rake file is no longer created (I think it's been absorbed into the gem).

So in conclusion, deleting rspec.rake made everything work again - both rake db:migrate and rspec spec.